# Form won't submit if chosen file is large

Tags: html, file, upload, size

I have an HTML-form that I use for uploading files (and some other data). The form is as follows:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="register.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="reason">Reason</label>
        <textarea id="reason" class="form-control" name="reason_text" rows="4"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="reason_file">Attachment</label>
        <input type="file" id="reason_file" name="reason_file">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="amount">Score</label>
        <input type="number" id="amount" class="form-control" name="amount">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="register" value="Register">
</form>
```

If I use this form with a rather small file, let's say 1 MB, it'll be just fine and my server-side can process it correctly. However, if I use a file that's for example 5.5 MB, the form will only redirect to the action-page (register.php) but it will not send any POST-data whatsoever. Or at least, when checking with PHP, both $_POST and $_FILES are completely empty.

Where is this file-size restriction based and how do I change it?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my server, post_max_size is smaller (quite a lot) then upload_max_filesize. The first is 3M while the latter is 64M. This is why I thought my limit would be at 64M but apparently is much lower. The fix is to change the following rule in php.ini:

```
post_max_size = 3M
```